# VBA Multilevel Regex or improved Pattern?

Tags: regex, vba

I have a problem processing a regex in VB. My Text is:

> is sadly currently in Toronto main station undetermined late

I tested my regex in Expresso and found this regex for my purpose. The thing is: Toronto main station can also be only "Toronto". So this is my pattern:

```
is sadly currently in (([A-Za-z]*)(\s|-)){1,3}(.|\s)*?undetermined
```

The problem is processing the regex in VB, because my Pattern gives me a result like this:

- is sadly currently in Toronto main station undetermined

  - undetermined

    - Toronto
    - Main
    - undetermined
  - undetermined

    - Toronto
    - Main
    - undetermined
      ....

But I cannot access the words toronto and main via VB - also I dont want 'undetermined' be part of the result. I tried `match.item(0).submatches.item(0).submatches.item(0)` but VBA already throws an error if I try `match.item(0).submatches.item(0).submatches` and states that there is no such object - obviously it cannot process some those "multilevel" regexes. Is there a way to improve my pattern so that I only have to use one submatches or is it possible to use multiple submatches via VBA?!

Edit:

```
GetDelay.Pattern = is sadly currently in (([A-Za-z]*)(\s|-)){1,3}(.|\s)*?undetermined"
GetDelay.IgnoreCase = True
GetDelay.Multiline = True
...
If GetDelay.TEst(MailBody) Then
        Set m = GetDelay.Execute(MailBody)
        If m.Item(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
            OrtBody = m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) + " " + m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(1)  'Error 424 comes here - Object required
            If GetReason.TEst(AbweichungsmailBody) Then
                Set m = GetReason.Execute(AbweichungsmailBody)
                If m.Item(0).SubMatches.Count > 0 Then
                    Reason= m.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
                Else
                    Reason= "Error!"
                End If
            Else
                Reason = "Keine Angabe gefunden!"
            End If
        Else
            thisfunction= False
        End If
    Else
        thisfunction= False
    End If
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to apply the regex and how you try to retrieve the result. I don't understand what you mean with "multilevel" regex.

Comment: Do you want to use vb.net or VBA? your question is tagged `vb.net`, but the title says `VBA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capturing results from a repeated sub-expression (in your case `(([A-Za-z]*)(\s|-)){1,3}`) gets tricky in any language.  I suggest the following as a simpler approach:

1) Match the whole portion you are interested in with a simple Regex:

```
GetDelay.Pattern = "is sadly currently in (.*?) undetermined"
```

2) Once you have matched the portion of interest, perform further analysis to get what you want.  You could use another RegEx for this step, though I think you could just [`Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with a space as the delimiter.